# Does g++ compiler simplify expressions?

Tags: c++, templates, g++

Does g++ compiler replace `*&x` by `x`?

Does it do it in the following case?

```
int x;

template <int *ptr>
void print_var(){
    printf("%d\n", *ptr);
}

main(){
    print_var <&x> ();
}
```

Comment: There is no `*&` in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The C++ standard allows the compiler to make any optimization it can as long as the semantics are the same. It's called the as-if rule:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if

In practice compilers do a good job of aggressively inlining instantiated template code and simplifying it. Let's look at what x86-64 assembly g++ generates for a simpler test case:
https://godbolt.org/z/x5rreG

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
int x;

template <int *ptr>
void print_var(){
    printf("%d\n", *ptr);
}

void test(){
    print_var <&x> ();
}
```

The generated assembly is this:

```
.LC0:
        .string "%d\n"
test():
        mov     esi, DWORD PTR x[rip] ; pass x to printf
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0 ; pass "%d\n" to printf
        xor     eax, eax              ; return value register
        jmp     printf                ; call
x:
        .zero   4
```

The compiler doesn't waste any instructions storing the pointer separately and dereferencing it.